# webdriver click on img tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<td>
    <a id="userid_popup" onclick="openLookupWinNew('/oasis/UserLookup.do', 400, 270, 'userid_input', 'assignToUserId', 'uiAssignToUserId', false)" name="userid_popup">
        <img class="icon" title="Users" alt="Users" src="/oasis/images/search_button1.gif" style="background-color: transparent;">
    </a>
    <input id="hide" type="button" style="display: none">
</td>
```

on clicking the img take it opens a popup window

I tried following code, 
`@FindBy(css = "#userid_popup>img")
                         private WebElement lookupButton;`

1. `lookupButton.click()` --> ElementNotVisibleException
2. `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].click();", lookupButton)` --> **Even though it click it hangs there itself , no statements execute after that ..**

Any help on this?

Comment: Due to the exception you've noted, is the element actually visible at the time you're trying to execute the `.click();`?

Comment: Good to know, just checking. Although I do have to ask, is there any particular reason you're trying to click on the `img` tag and not the `anchor` itself?

Answer (score 0):

0) Ensure there's no AJAX or other async stuff going on. Mark asked that, but it's worth double-checking. Just add in an explicit wait for the img element and see if that helps. (No, do NOT use Thread.Sleep() or something similar. :) )

1) Move your click target to the anchor tag. Unless you have something wired up explicitly to the  element then a click action there isn't going to do anything. It's the  element that actually spawns your popup window. (Which you can see in the HTML snippet above, too!)

Good luck!